# Hdfs-Sink Connector created data-duplication as per file name

Tags: apache-kafka, hive, hdfs, parquet, apache-kafka-connect

As per my understanding of HDFS 2 Sink, connector does exactly once delivery with help of write ahead logs and connector manages offset commit by encoded Kafka offset information into HDFS files.

In my environment: installed 3-nodes Kafka cluster as well as same number of HDFS2Sink connectors with hive integration are running in my lab. I am ingesting large datasets to Kafka like 500k/hr. Due to some Kerberos issue  connectors are being restarted around 12 hours once.

Created parquet files in hive topic directory/path. Sometimes, observed repeated inserted offsets as per parquet file creation pattern by HDFS 2 Sink connectors. I shared parquet files as shown below:

```
-rw-rw-r--   3 hdfs supergroup    2341466 2021-03-18 06:02 /data/test/input/topics/testdata/day=2021-03-18/hour=04/quarter=4/testdata+2+161638453251+161639013250.parquet
-rw-rw-r--   3 hdfs supergroup    2383185 2021-03-18 06:02 /data/test/input/topics/testdata/day=2021-03-18/hour=04/quarter=4/testdata+2+161638454059+161638453250.parquet
-rw-rw-r--   3 hdfs supergroup    8725160 2021-03-18 06:03 /data/test/input/topics/testdata/day=2021-03-18/hour=04/quarter=4/testdata+2+161639013251+161639573250.parquet
```

1st Parquet file name **i.e.** testdata+2+161638453251+161639013250.parquet, it means that this file contains from start offset i.e. 161638453251 to end offset i.e.161639013250. There is a possibility that some offsets may not contains which are not matching schema or parsing errors. But we can observe in the dead queue.

If we observe 2nd file name i.e. testdata+2+**161638454059**+**161638453250**.parquet carefully, start offset i.e. 161638454059 and end offsets i.e.161638453250 are already present in first file itself. I believe entire 2nd file contains 559191 records as per offsets (assume nothing wrong records as per schema) are duplicated. Correct me if my understanding is wrong,

Is there any possibility connector will be inserted previous offset again after rebalancing connector/worker tasks.

Connectors configuration:

```
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
  "flush.size": "560000",
  "connect.hdfs.principal": "hdfs/xxxxxxyz",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "timezone": "UTC",
  "hive.database": "test",
  "rotate.interval.ms": "-1",
  "locale": "en-us",
  "hive.tableNames": "testdata",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat",
  "hive.integration": "true",
  "hive.conf.dir": "/etc/kafka-connect/hive",
  "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
  "hadoop.conf.dir": "/etc/kafka-connect/hadoop",
  "schema.compatibility": "BACKWARD",
  "connect.hdfs.keytab": "/etc/security/kerberos/keytabs/hdfs.keytab",
  "topics": "testdata",
  "hdfs.url": "hdfs://abc/data/test/input",
  "hdfs.authentication.kerberos": "true",
  "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://xyz-1:9083,thrift://xyz-2:9083",
  "partition.field.name": "day,hour,quarter",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.FieldPartitioner",
  "name": "test-hdfs_sink_connector-testdata",
  "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
  "timestamp.field": "collection_time"
}
```

What could be cause of duplication as per file name at Connectors; Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: `161638454059+161638453250.parquet` How is it possible to have descending order? starting is 4059, ending is 3250.

Comment: This behaviour observed in dev cluster. not sure reason

Comment: did you resolve this error? Or living with the same? or moved on to a different solution? And have you seen the error again?